# How to use the link function in angular js custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I had went through the angular guide regarding the custom directives. I came across the link function in custom directive. I was unable to understand the concept & using the link function. Please can any one share a small functionality with explanation regarding the link function & it's parameters.

Comment: Go through https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

**Directives are compiled inthe following steps**

1. The $compile traverses the DOM and looks for directives. For each directive it finds, it adds it to a list of directives.
2. Once the entire DOM has been traversed, it will sort that list of directives by their priority. Then, each directive’s own compile function is executed, giving each directive the chance to modify the DOM itself. Each compile function returns a linking function, which is then composed into a combined linking function and returned.
3. $compile links the template with the scope by calling the combined linking function from the previous step. This in turn will call the linking function of the individual directives, registering listeners

**Compile** – This compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.
Use the compile function to change the original DOM (template element) before AngularJS creates an instance of it and before a scope is created.
**Post-Link** – This is executed after the child elements are linked. It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function.
Use the post-link function to execute logic, knowing that all child elements have been compiled and all pre-link and post-link functions of child elements have been executed.
**Pre-Link** – This is executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate the correct elements for linking.
Use the pre-link function to implement logic that runs when AngularJS has already compiled the child elements, but before any of the child element's post-link functions have been called.   Compile vs Link

var app = angular.module('app', []); function createDirective(name) { return function () { return { restrict: 'E', compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) { console.log(name + ': compile'); return { pre: function (scope, iElem, attrs) { console.log(name + ': pre link'); },
32

post: function (scope, iElem, attrs) { console.log(name + ': post link'); } } } } } } app.directive('levelOne', createDirective('level-One')); app.directive('levelTwo', createDirective('level-Two')); app.directive('levelThree', createDirective('level-Three'));       Hello {{name}}

Answer (score 0):

link function params follows

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
}
```

- scope is an Angular scope object.
- element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
- attrs is an object with the normalized attribute names and their corresponding values